# parallel opencl kernel execution

Tags: opencl, open-closed-principle, opencl-c

I am trying to execute multiple kernels in parallel. Each kernel is independent of each other. I am trying to execute the kernel on GPU. What I think is out of order execution and enqueue each kernel separately. Is that the way to approach this problem or there can other way around to it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [avoid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) using image of text data at all cost. Please edit your question to replace the image by the code in appropriate formating.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: OpenCL is existing to run same kernels on arrays of data. of course u can run multiple kernels in parallel and use events for sync. also u can make super kernel with IF condition which runs different subkernel but thats inefficient

Comment: I know that we can execute multiple kernels in parallel, I just wanted to confirm that what I think of executing kernels in out of order and enqueue each kernel separately is the way to go or I can do that in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Create an out-of-order queue and enqueue both kernels.
2. Create two queues and enqueue one kernel to each.